# In autosys host, one particular path .lck files are automatically creating

Tags: linux, ubuntu, job-scheduler, job-control, autosys

We have a autosys host, In particular active path , automatically .lck files are created.
Due to this, We could see success runs but our Portal is not getting synced as per the Job run scheduled for every 5min.Observing some delay in syncing the portal even though Job has ran successfully.

Also we could see .lck files are getting generated under active path.We tried removing them but still they are getting generated.
When .lck files are removed, we could see portal is getting synced properly.

Can someone please assist on this case.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Due to overload for that specific host .lck files are created.
After load decrease the server behaves normal